# How to fix "error: not found: type CosmosDBSourceProvider" in databricks scala read stream from cosmos db

Tags: scala, apache-spark, azure-cosmosdb, databricks

I'm trying to use scala on databricks to read stream from the cosmos db by following from this source: https://learn.microsoft.com/bs-latn-ba/azure/cosmos-db/spark-connector 
but somehow the example of scala read stream code didn't work for me.

I've been trying to import more libraries, such as "com.microsoft.azure.cosmosdb.spark.streaming._" but it still didn't work.

this is the scala code I'm trying to use

```
import com.microsoft.azure.cosmosdb.spark.schema._
import com.microsoft.azure.cosmosdb.spark._
import com.microsoft.azure.cosmosdb.spark.config.Config

val readConfig = Config(Map(
  "Endpoint" -> cosmos_endpoint,
  "Masterkey" -> cosmos_masterkey,
  "Database" -> "abc",
  "Collection" -> "123",
  "ReadChangeFeed" -> "true",
  "ChangeFeedQueryName" -> "Scala-Changefeed",
  "ChangeFeedStartFromTheBeginning" -> "true",
  "InferStreamSchema" -> "false",
  "ChangeFeedCheckpointLocation" -> ".../ChagefeedCheckpoint"))

 val changeFeed = spark.readStream.format(classOf[CosmosDBSourceProvider].getName).options(readConfig).load()
```

and the error message I got was

```
command-2054522864350223:16: error: not found: type CosmosDBSourceProvider
val changeFeed = spark.readStream.format(classOf[CosmosDBSourceProvider].getName).options(readConfig).load()
                                                 ^
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you didn't import some class. 
I think you can replace

```
.format(classOf[CosmosDBSourceProvider].getName)
```

by

```
.format("com.microsoft.azure.cosmosdb.spark.streaming.CosmosDBSourceProvider")
```